# file type options under properties on dolphin does not work. Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dolphin, toshiba, file-type

I have installed dolphin, additional to Nautilus on Ubuntu 16.04. When I select a file and go to properties and press the file type options button nothing happens. A window showing possible applications should appear but nothing happens.
I'm using a Toshiba Portégé Z30-C-138.
Any idea of what is happening?

Thank you,

Javier

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo apt install kde-cli-tools
```

Fixed it for me in Xubuntu 18.04.

An explanation of what is happening: Dolphin is part of the KDE environment.  Nothing happened when you clicked the file type options button because Dolphin was trying to action another part of the KDE environment that was not installed.

Comment: Works for OpenSuse 42.3 as well.  zypper -v in kde-cli-tools5

Comment: Thanks, works for antiX 17.4.1 x386

Comment: also worked in archlinux ( that also pulled kdesu)

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 16.04 lts

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this problem as well on Lubuntu xenial 16.04.
Here is a workaround as follows:

- In Dolphin's GUI, right click the file of the type you want to change the default app for.
- Go to Open With >> Other....
- Select the program you want to be default and check the box "Remember application association for this type of file"
- Press OK to run the program and update the file-type association

It's not ideal, but it seems to work for me for the time being.

Comment: Thank you nikhe. As you said it's not ideal, but it works.
Best regards,
Javier